# PowerShell equivalent of RPROMPT

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell profile template that mimics the [lambda mod for zsh](https://github.com/halfo/lambda-mod-zsh-theme) as close as possible as a proof-of-concept.

I was able to get the lambda, the user colored if root and the home-abbreviated path right. The git part can be done using `posh-git`, but the repo hash displayed in the mod is **right aligned in the prompt line**.

Zash/Bash does this through a RPROMPT variable and I haven't found similar functionality in PowerShell. Does it really not exist? Is it possible to implement it?

If I were to implement how'd it go about? It seems to me it's impossible to reliably align something right on PS without the Shell size (and therefore breaking at resize). Also, I wouldn't know how to have the cursor still on the line that RPROMPT was written.

Comment: You can use [`$Host.UI.RawUI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.rawui) in a custom `prompt` function to futz with the console directly (including displaying stuff on the right), but I'm not sure you can make this robust in the face of resizing without an entirely custom host (since there's no resize events you can hook). You may need to settle for having it draw correctly only after every command, rather than immediately on resize. And even then command output could overwrite it, I suppose.

Comment: You could look at what Joel Bennett did with [PowerLine](https://github.com/Jaykul/PowerLine).

Comment: A quick test with raw UI output shows that PowerShell will erase the current line as soon as you start typing, and does not preserve such content on a resize. So the value for a prompt is limited, unless you don't mind displaying the information on a line other than the cursor (or you don't mind it's transient). In theory, the former limitation can be overcome by customizing `PSConsoleHostReadline`, but that's both complicated and not attractive to combine with [existing customizations](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine).

Comment: Thanks, @BenH, his code will help. It seems that he indeed uses `Console.BufferWidth` and escape codes to reposition the cursor.